# To those having the Object graph for type 'xxx' contains cycles

Tags: wcf

This is more of a share knowledge than anything else.  Wasn't sure if I was supposed to make it a question.

So I have multiple issues with the following error `Object graph for type 'xxx' contains cycles`

There are many ways the internet says to fix it, for instance adding the `IsReference=true` attribute, creating your own custom attributes, etc.

For me I find the most simplest way is by just making the child parent object have a private setter.

ie.

```
public ParentObject objectName { get; private set; }
```

More in depth example.

```
public class Parent()
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Child()
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; private set; }
    public int ChildProp { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give the credit to this post correct answer(in green), for helping me figure it out.

[http://forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1773164.aspx/1)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.